# Build docker image with argument in FROM failed

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, containers, fabric8

I want to pass argument outside to my dockerfile. Argument should be part of FROM command. So, I have Dockerfile below:

```
ARG argument=123
FROM baseImage:$argument
```

But when I am trying to build it I receive the error below:

DOCKER> Unable to check image [baseImage:$argument] : no such image: baseImage:$argument: **invalid reference format (Bad Request: 400)**

Docker version

```
Client:
 Version:       17.12.1-ce
 API version:   1.35
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    7390fc6
 Built: Tue Feb 27 22:15:20 2018
 OS/Arch:       linux/amd64

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      17.12.1-ce
  API version:  1.35 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.4
  Git commit:   7390fc6
  Built:        Tue Feb 27 22:17:54 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

Reading documentation I see such format is correct, however it doesn't work. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is with fabric8 plugin. 
Described [here](http://github.com/moby/moby/releases/tag/v17.05.0-ce)

For now I added placeholders to Dockerfile and used maven-resources-plugin with filtering in order to replace placeholders with values. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Old versions of Docker don't support `ARG` before `FROM`. I don't remember the exact version it was changed, but I believe the support was added after the 17.X line.

Comment: I saw somewhere that  it was presented in versions greater than 17.05

Comment: @liotur They added multi-image build support in 17.05, and the ARG before FROM support came at some point after that, but I'm not sure it was around by version 17.12.

Comment: Look here, I see one of the features exactly what I need - https://github.com/moby/moby/releases/tag/v17.05.0-ce

Comment: By the way, I am using also fabric8 plugin, maybe there is an option with templating the dockerfile?

Comment: It might be fabric8 - the syntax you posted is definitely valid with the latest Docker builds. I would suspect either the old Docker version or fabric8 as being the problem.

Comment: Just build with simple docker build command - it worked. So the issue indeed in maven fabric8 plugin. Do you have an idea how to fix that?

Comment: Super strange thing happens. I changed the argument to "version" and succeeded to build the image. Tried to change it to "something_version" - failure. "something-version" - failure. "somethingVersion" - failed. How it is possible??? Why only argument with name "version" ? Is is some saved word?

Comment: Definitely something related to plugin. Because in pure docker command I can add any name of argument in docker file

Comment: Ok, looks like I found the issue 

https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin/issues/859

Indeed some limitation in plugin. Don't really understand how overcome this